# What is shirk in love?

Tags: shirk

What is shirk in love? Is it that if a person loves his parents or his children very much, he automatically becomes a polytheist? Or is it related only to the form of worship?

Comment: If you breathe oxygen, then you're a polytheist. Does this answer your question ? Why is the site flooded with so many weird ( or stupid , if being rude) questions nowadays related to shirk etc. ? Many of them are of repeating nature too.